# Facing issue in setting proxy using headless chrome

Tags: python, gitlab, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

**I'm trying to launch the URL using headless chrome from GIT(CI/CD) with Docker. When I execeute my script it gets failed. I can see from the log report that browser is not launched.I've tried following scenarios**

## Scenario 1 Tried setting proxy in Python (Custom library) and invoked the function from Robot framework

```
def Chrome_browser_options():
    PROXY = "http://<RemoteIPAddress:host>"
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")    
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY)
    return    chrome_options
```

Invoked the python function in Robot Framework, Chrome browser is not working

```
${chrome options}=    Chrome_browser_options
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome options}
Go To    https://www.google.com/
```

For Scenario 1, No error message is diplayed, but I can see from the log report that browser is not launched,blank screenshot displayed in output.

## Scenario 2: Tried setting proxy in Create Webdriver using Headless Chrome

```
${chrome_options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    headless
Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    disable-gpu
${options}=     Call Method     ${chrome_options}    to_capabilities      

Create Webdriver    Remote   command_executor=http://<RemoteIPAddres:host>    desired_capabilities=${options}
Go to     https://www.google.com/
```

For Scenario 2, getting error as

```
WebDriverException: Message: <html><head><title>504 Gateway Timeout</title></head>
        <body><h1>Gateway Timeout</h1>
        <p>Server error - server RemoteIpAddress is unreachable at this moment.<br><br>Please retry the request or contact your administrator.<br></body></html>
```

## Scenario 3: Tried setting proxy in Open Browser using Headless Chrome

```
 ${chrome_options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    disable-gpu
    ${options}=     Call Method     ${chrome_options}    to_capabilities     

    Open Browser    https://www.google.com/   browser=chrome   remote_url=http://<RemoteIPAddres:host>      desired_capabilities=${options}
```

For Scenario 3, getting error as

```
WebDriverException: Message: <html><head><title>504 Gateway Timeout</title></head>
<body><h1>Gateway Timeout</h1>
<p>Server error - server RemoteIpAddress is unreachable at this moment.<br><br>Please retry the request or contact your administrator.<br></body></html>
```

Kindly let me know, If any solution for this issue.

Comment: I see error in your python code. At the beginning of the function you declare `PROXY` variable and it already include `http://` and at the end building `--proxy-server` argument you add once more.

Comment: Thanks @JaPyR After removing http from PROXY variable it worked.